# While running recorded simulation in Gatling, I get an error

Tags: compilation, gatling

While running recorded simulation in Gatling.

I get an error:

> "Resource /recordedsimulation/0004.request.dat"/"Resource
>   /recordedsimulation/0004.request.json" not found?

Comment: Where your resources are located? What is the path specified in requests?  Are you running script using maven or directly using gatling?
Error states quite clearly that resources can't be found, thus if they exist, it's a path error most likely. Also this might be useful: location of JSON files in src/gatling/resources/bodies default removal not clearly documented[](https://github.com/lkishalmi/gradle-gatling-plugin/issues/74)

Answer (score 4):

You have to open your simulation file, for instance: recordedsimulation.scala and replace all error occurrences of first slash in your file path.

For instance use:

```
.body(RawFileBody("recordedsimulation/0004.request.json"))
```

instead of:

```
.body(RawFileBody("/recordedsimulation/0004.request.json"))
```

And make sure, your directory recordedsimulation is in your resources directory if you are using gatling version greater than 3.